# Android debug server protocol version mismatch

Tags: android

I am trying to debug an arm64 binary in /data/local/tmp of my Android phone. I pushed the /dbgsrv/android_server64 to /data/local/tmp and then adb to the phone:

`$ chmod 777 ./android_server64
$ ./android_server64
IDA Android 32-bit remote debug server(ST) v1.20. Hex-Rays (c) 2004-2015
Listening on port #23946...
[1] Accepting connection from 127.0.0.1...`

And when I connect to it with IDA, the target outputs:

`[1] Incompatible IDA version
[1] Closing connection from 127.0.0.1...`

And the host gets an error window:

`Incompatible debugging server:
protocol version is 20, expected 21`

Do I have to update IDA to get v21 debug servers? Are the updated debug servers posted somewhere?

Comment: I think asking on IDA support forums will be more productive.